# What would happen to Eurozone and EU if Italy defaults on its debt?

Tags: macroeconomics, government-debt, international-economics, euro-area, italy

### Question

***What would happen to Eurozone and EU if Italy defaults on its debt?***

### Background & disclaimer

This direct question is an attempt to amend [the more expanded question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/42049/what-exactly-is-the-risk-italys-high-debt-to-gdp-ratio-poses-to-eurozone-and-eu?noredirect=1#comment66394_42049).

Given that [this question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/17476/what-would-happen-if-the-us-defaults-on-its-debt?rq=1) is not closed speculative, my hope is this one is equally well posed.

Comment: It might be helpful to copy the question into the question text, as well as the title. Right now, it looks like a typical empty nonsense question, until you realize the title is the question.

Comment: @user253751 Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: It may not be closed but likely only get the same opinion / guess based answer as the similar IS default question, if it gets any. I invite you to read what was speculated when Greece was in big trouble, and compare it to the current outcome.  People become extremely adaptive, and very good problem solvers when all hell breaks loose, so I am inclined to believe it will be less doomsday than many others may think. This is purely opinion based though and I have no way to back this believe.